# How do classify class when there's a tie using a K value in KNN

Tags: machine-learning, knn

so I had this question I was debating on with a friend.

The questions goes like what should be the minimum value of  K, so that "Naeem" can be classified as:

1. F
2. B

Here are the values the distances I calculated given the matrix:

```
Name    | A     | B     | C | Class| Distance from Naeem
--------|-------|-------|---|------|--------------------
'Kamran'| 35    | 35    | 3 | 'A'  | 15.17
'Zahid' | 22    | 50    | 2 | 'B'  | 15.0
'Imran' | 63    | 200   | 1 | 'C'  | 152.24
'Azfer' | 59    | 170   | 1 | 'D'  | 122.0
'Raza'  | 25    | 40    | 4 | 'E'  | 15.75
'Aamir' | 35    | 150   | 1 | 'A'  | 100.02
'Zia'   | 25    | 120   | 3 | 'B'  | 71.03
'Ishrat'| 26    | 90    | 4 | 'C'  | 41.53
'Khalid'| 40    | 60    | 2 | 'F'  | 10.44
'Naeem' | 37    | 50    | 2 | ?    |
```

Now we agree that for Naeem to be of class F, K will be 1.
However when it comes for Naeem to be of class B, he says that it'll be K=3 because that's the first time that B class is considered as nearest neighbour, but I say that for classification we need not to have ties of classes which K=3 will bring (F,A,B) and rather we need to use K=4 so that we have two neighbours with class B and as majority wins, Naeem will be classified as B only when K=4.

Any insights on who's correct or we are both understanding something wrong?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up @desertnaut, posting it there

Comment: You are welcome; when you do so please delete this one, as cross-posting is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me,  for 'Naeem' to be classified as 'F' value of K must be equal to one.

When it comes for "Naeem" to be of class B, value of K must be number that has a  majority of B. We achieve majority of B when value of K is set to 6.

- K=1 gives {F}
- K=2 gives {F,B}
- K=3 gives {F,B,A}
- K=4 gives {F,B,A,E}
- K=5 gives {F,B,A,E,C}
- K=6 gives {F,B,A,E,C,B}

for k=6, all other variable have 1 repetitions and B has 2 , so then 'Naeem' will be classified as B

Comment: By the way, Nice Question. Loved solving it and do correct me if I am wrong by any ways.

Comment: You were correct, just confirmed from a teacher too :)